# Get the selected option of select & show the selected option in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have tried a lot & searched a lot but i didn't found the solution.

I have HTML code

HTML

```
<form id="program_mode" action="" method="post">
        <select name="mode" id="mode">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $vars['url']?>pg/event_calendar/all" <?php if($mode == 'All') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>All</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $vars['url']?>pg/event_calendar/anytime" <?php if($mode == 'Online') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Online</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $vars['url']?>pg/event_calendar/offline" <?php if($mode == 'Offline') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Offline</option>
        </select>
        </form>
```

Then i want in php part the selected option.

So i have written like

PHP

```
$mode = $_POST['mode'];
var_dump($mode);
```

But i am not getting the value. The thing i dont want to submit. Onchange only it should get the value. Can it will be possible ?

Comment: it would require javascript

Comment: @RIADev What's the output of `echo $mode;` and are you sending the form with option as "Select" ?

Comment: in value of select options should be in your `$mode` (All, Offline or Online) then you got selected. what is the value in your `$mode`

Comment: @wribit See i am new to it. With out java script can it will be possible ? If not then i will get the value in java script but how to get in PHP again.

Comment: I am getting NULL value for $mode

Comment: @RIADev Are you submitting the form with the selected option as "Select" and how do you submit your form ? I can't see any `<input type='submit'/>` in the form

Comment: he doesn't want to submit the form...

Comment: @RIADev So you want to use **AJAX** ?

Comment: Any thing i can use but need the value in PHP with out submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="program_mode" action="" method="post">
    <select name="mode" id="mode" onchange="val_changed()">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $vars['url']?>pg/event_calendar/all" <?php if($mode == 'All') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>All</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $vars['url']?>pg/event_calendar/anytime" <?php if($mode == 'Online') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Online</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $vars['url']?>pg/event_calendar/offline" <?php if($mode == 'Offline') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Offline</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

With little jquery you can do with this

```
    <script>
function val_changed()
        {
        var mode=$('#mode').val();

        }
</script>
```

Comment: How to pass this value again to the PHP.

Comment: use $.post("your_file.php", {mode:$('#mode').val();}); and remove var mode=$('#mode').val();

Answer (score 0):

Ya sure, if you want to submit the form you can use `form.submit()` in onchange event of the dropdown like:

```
<select name="mode" id="mode" onchange="form.submit();">
```

And can access the value in PHP like:

```
if(isset($_POST['mode'])){
    var_dump($_POST['mode']);
    //extra code    
}
```

If you dont want to submit the form you can just use a `jquery` function to pick the selected value: Then remove the onchange event handler from select box as:

```
<select name="mode" id="mode">
```

and just add the following jquery function:

```
$('#mode').change(function(e) {
    var val =   $(this).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

Comment: So the PHP part should be inside the form or outside ?

Comment: I don't think he wants to submit the form, namely refresh the page though

Answer (score 0):

If you want PHP to get the value only when the option is change, you should use JavaScript or jQuery.
Include the **jQuery** library :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Then add the following code in a `<script></script>` tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#mode").change(function(){
  $.post("php_file.php", {mode:$(this).val()});
 });
});
```

When the option changes, jQuery will send a **POST** request in the background to the `php_file.php` with `mode` value. PHP will take care of the rest.

This works normally like a form submitted to the PHP file. So you will get the `$_POST['mode']` value in the PHP file.

Comment: @RIADev You should mention the URL of file by replacing the `php_file.php` in code.

Comment: Okay i know that i am asking will it work for the same file ?

Comment: In PHP side i need to write like $mode = $_POST['mode'] right ?

Comment: @RIADev Yes, the `$_POST['mode']` will have the value of the current option value.

Comment: NO buddy its not working..okay i will try some other alternatives