# When i redirect my php to another php i stop getting mails

Tags: php

i have a slight issue with some php-code i have recently gotten an answer to:
[Tutorials for passing value data to email with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851620/tutorials-for-passing-value-data-to-email-with-php)

my first php code was:

```
<?php
  if($_REQUEST['submit']=='Submit'){
    $user_type=$_REQUEST['user_type'];
    $sen=$_REQUEST['SEN'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $product=$_REQUEST['product'];
    $product_specify=$_REQUEST['product_specify'];
    $license_choice=$_REQUEST['license_choice'];

    $to = 'nobody@example.com'; //to whom the email have to besnd
    $message = "User Type: $user_type \n Sen: $sen \n Email: $email \n Product:   $product \n Product Specified: $product_specify \n License: $license_choice"; //content of the email
    $subject = 'hello';  //shown as subject of the email
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . //eamil header information
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
      echo "Mail Sucessfully Sent";
    } else {
      echo "Something went wrong";
    }
  }
?>
```

and that worked fine and i received the data in my mailbox but when i replace the last lines (starting from if(mail($to...) with

```
header('Location: thanks.php');
exit();
```

i do not receive any mails anymore. I need to redirect it to another page because there is some styling applied there. Am i doing something wrong?

By the way, i wanted to continue this discussion on the topic before but can i only continue through comments or by editing my original post? And if i do the latter, will people notice this change? Thx

Comment: did you said you replace from `if (mail...`? then you are deleting mail function itself. You should replace `echo "mail sent...` message with header function.

Comment: So, when you remove the code that sends the mail, you do not receive mail anymore...?! Hmmm, how peculiar.

Comment: i thought as much ;) pretty clear that i have no php-knowledge...

Answer (score 2):

Don't replace if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)). Just use below code and will be success :

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
   header('Location: thanks.php');
   exit();
} else {
   echo "Something went wrong";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

is the command you execute to send the email. 
To get your result you have to write your code like this:

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
header('Location: thanks.php');
} else {
header('Location: fail.php');
}
```

This way the user will be redirected to a different page: thanks.php if the mail is sent correctly and fail.php if the mail is not sent.

Comment: it works. slowly we're getting there ;)